# UIDocumentInteractionController: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, xcode, unrecognized-selector, uidocumentinteraction

I am using `UIDocumentInteractionController` to share a document (PDF) with other apps.

The view with the different apps shows up just fine but when I press any of the apps to open/save/share the file, my app crashes.

I get the `Unrecognised selector sent to instance` error.

It seems that the error comes from the file url I give to (not sure tho):

```
[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
```

**DocumentInteractionManager.h**:

```
@interface DocumentInteractionManager : UIViewController <UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIDocumentInteractionController* documentInteractionController;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSURL *url;

- (void)openDocumentFromRect:(UIView*)view withURL:(NSURL*)fileUrl;

@end
```

**DocumentInteractionManager.m**:

```
@implementation DocumentInteractionManager

@synthesize documentInteractionController;
@synthesize url;

//fileUrl is something like: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/[APP]/Library/file.pdf
- (void)openDocumentFromRect:(UIView*)view withURL:(NSURL*)fileUrl {

    self.url = fileUrl;
    if (url) {
        documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:self.url];

        // Configure Document Interaction Controller
        [documentInteractionController setDelegate:self];
        CGRect rect = [view frame];

        [documentInteractionController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:[view frame] inView:view animated:YES];
    }
}


@end
```

**EDIT:**

Here is how I am creating the url: `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfPath]`

Note that it works when I use `UIActivityViewController` and share via AirDrop

**EDIT2:**

Here are some of the different messages I get (depending on which app I choose):

- iBooks: `[__NSCFString URL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`
- Copy: [OS_dispatch_queue URL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
- Email: [NSISLinearExpression URL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Show the whole error message, especially the selector name unrecognized.

Comment: @Larme Actually, it changes depending on the app I want to use.
On iBooks it's : `[__NSCFString URL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` when on Drpobox it's: `[NSISEngine URL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've figured it out.

What I was doing wrong was that I was instantiating `UIDocumentInteractionController` in the `- (void)openDocumentFromRect:(UIView*)view withURL:(NSURL*)fileUrl` method. So basically when I was out of that method `UIDocumentInteractionController` was destroyed.

I now instantiate `UIDocumentInteractionController` in the init method and voilà it works as expected.